# Using a Dictionary for Text Mining

Tags: dictionary

I want to use a dictionary to analyze a text with text mining mechanisms.

So I'm looking for a dictionary with scores for each words, so for example the word "cool", +1, gets a positive score, the word "and" a neutral score, 0, and the word "bad" a negative score, -1.

Where can I find a dictionary with words and scores?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/) which is dedicated to that purpose.